# How to process Hipaa-5010-837P-ClaimPayment in azure intregation account

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, edi, x12

I want to process below sample file in Azure logic app

https://support.edifabric.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000369472-HIPAA-5010-837P-Professional-Claim

Is it possible to process this?

Comment: There are many ways to process file, what way you tend to use? HTTP or storage or other ways

Answer (score 0):

First you need to [create an integration account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account), add [partners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-partners).

Then please follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-x12) to add agreement and configure your agreement.

After that, you need to configure X12 encoding and X12 decoding in your logic app.

As I don't know the details of your scene, so here is an example which the another user do the similar to yours: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5ef49ad9-8868-4bf3-931b-9ad32b554378/x12-error-during-schema-validation-of-edi-837-azure-logic-apps?forum=azurelogicapps